# Sql server 2008 best way to turn hard coded references to schema name into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell

We have a database that has been cobbled together over the years.  When I export it as a.sql file script even with the options to explicitly refer to the schema name removed a lot of stored procedures use the hard coded schema name [EpicDB].

I have a small powershell utility that is table to reconstruct a versioned database by running   the various .sql files we have to make the db in order.  Some of these files have hundreds of references to [EpicDB].

How can I pass a variable name from my powershell/.net code to an sql script to swap out [EpicDB] for a variable?

Answer (score 0):

sqlcmd.exe and "SqlCmd Mode" allows for variables.

You'll have to change your

```
[EpicDB]
```

text

to something like

```
[$(MyDatabaseName)]
```

See:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx